# Rectangle photo in database auto rotate when display

Tags: php, html, mysql

this is how I insert image into database and how I display it,all of those code are on a same page.
If anyone know about why my image will rotate when display out,please tell me.
Any kind of help will be appreciated :)

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()" name="registration" method="post" >

                <div class="item form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >User Image: <span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input  id="name"  name="userImage" type="file" />
                    </div> 
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
                    <button id="send" type="submit" name="subtn" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </form>

if(count($_FILES) > 0) 
{
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) 
        {
    if(isset($_POST["subtn"]))  
    {   

        $imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
        $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);


        $sqlregister = "insert into users (imageType ,imageData) 

                                            values  ('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')                                    
                       ";



    <div class="profile_pic">
    <a  href="editProfile.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
    <?php 
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $img ).'"  height="50" width="70" class="img-circle profile_img" />';   
    ?>
    </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any strange CSS being applied? It really shouldn't rotate.

Comment: omg,maybe is my team mate did it.
lot of css inside my code,thank for you hint.
I try find it out

Comment: forgot to tell you,the photo with square are function normally.only those image rectangle will rotate